# How to add the db.Column integer in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a function that current user will add budget and will get the average budget. But I don't how to properly get the user budget.

I tried this to get the current user budget:
routes.py:

```
@app.route("/user/<int:user_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/<int:user_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user(user_id):
    budget_count = Budgets.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).count()
    total_budget = Budgets.query.all()
    total_budget = current_user.current_budget
    added_budget = 0
    for budget in total_budget:
        added_budget = added_budget + budget
    average_budget = added_budget / budget_count
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    return render_template("user.html", title=current_user.username, user=user, budget_count=budget_count, average_budget=average_budget)
```

It gets and TypeError.

models.py:

```
class Budgets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    new_budget = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    expense = db.relationship('Expenses', backref='budget_expenses', lazy=True)
```

Is there any function or method so I can easily query and get the average of the data that I queried?

Comment: On which line did you get a TypeError, and exactly what did it say?  And, BTW, you set `total_budget = Budgets.query_all()` and then immediately overwrite that with `total_budget = current_user.current_budget`.  Did you intend for `total_budget` to be the `new_budget` column from `Budgets`?

Comment: I already solved the problem. I just added `budget.new_budget` and I also remove the `total_budget` that I queried, thank you for that.